# Building a winform app in VS for windows 7 x64 - get an error on install

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-studio-2005, windows-7, 64-bit

I have a winform application that i desiged in VS2005 that works fine in windows 7 x86 however when i try to install it on x64 I get the error:

"You have to run the 64-bit version of DPinst.exe on this machine. Contact the vendor that provided you this package. "

In VS I have the build set to 'Any CPU' which should handle 64bit. I cant seem to find much on that error online, any ideas? Is it something i need to change in VS before the build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/d/6/5d6eaf2b-7ddf-476b-93dc-7cf0072878e6/32-64bit_install.docx

Comment: this seems pretty complex, is there no simple settings I can do in visual studio to make this work? 

My solution is set up as my winform project and a Setup (deployment) project. CAn i alter properties in the deployment project to handle this?

Comment: Not that I know of. I've never seen the error myself, I just looked around and that was the only applicable information I found.